# how to create a list of data in Perl

Tags: perl, file, csv, average

I have a file.txt who contains data as follows:

```
word = blabla
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
word = blabla_b
a = 11
b = 22
c = 33
```

(basically, this file is a created by a java code that writes into this file the numbers that "a" contains, after that "b" and "c" in a certain loop, obviously a,b,c 1,2,3 are just an example, i have different names and different numbers :-) )

What I need to do is:

1. Read from the file that was given from the CMD
2. Write it to a CSV file (to be opened by excel) and on the bottom of every column (except from "word" since it is not numeric) to have the average: (i know how to calculate average in excel file but I want the script to do it by itself)

It should look like this in the end:

[image]

i did something not generic that it working but is very stupid and I’m sure there could be a more elegant way!!!

```
my $in_file = shift;  
my $fileName = "CSV_file";
open $out_file, ">$fileName.csv" or die "can't open $fileName: $!";
my @fields = ("word","a","b","c");
foreach (@fields)
{   
    #first write down the line of the headlines per each column
    print $out_file "$_,";  
}
print $out_file "\n";
open STATS, "<$in_file" or die "Error opening file \$in_file";
local($counter) = 0;
#creating avg and sum variables for each column - not clever once i'll have much more columns!!!!!!!!!
my $avgA = 0 , $avgB = 0 ,$avgC = 0;
my $sumA = 0 , $sumB = 0 ,$sumC = 0;

my $numOfRows = 0;
while (<STATS>)
{
    chop;
    ($name, $number) = split("=");  
    print $out_file "$number";

    if ($counter == $#fields) #end of row
    {
        print $out_file "\n";
        $sumC += $number;
        $counter = 0;
        $numOfRows++;
    }
    else
    {
        print $out_file ",";
        $counter++;
    }
    #adding to the Sum of each column (in order for future Avg calc)
    if ($counter == 2)
    {
        $sumA += $number;
    }
    elsif ($counter == 3)
    {
        $sumB += $number;
    }
}
$avgA = $sumA/$numOfRows;
$avgB = $sumB/$numOfRows;
$avgC = $sumC/$numOfRows;


print $out_file "AVG:,$avgA ,$avgB,$avgC \n";
close (FILE);
```

Comment: Can you show us the code, not just a picture of the code.

Comment: To show other people code on the internet, please copy and paste it into a site like http://gist.github.com

Comment: i tried, it won't let me.. it says that there is an error..

Comment: Your real question here is, "How do i write better Perl?" The answer to that is that you can learn it by reading "Modern Perl" and "Beginning Perl" by Ovid, which you can find linked on http://perl-tutorial.org Your code shows that you're at the very beginning stages of learning Perl and your question is open-ended (something which often leads to questions being closed on SO). If you read those two texts you'll gain a much better understanding and will be able to ask specific questions.

Comment: You tried what exactly? What was the exact error you got?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5662895

Comment: Yeah, with that code there are MANY things that can be improved, too many to explain them here. If you start reading the texts in my answer you'll quickly find improvements. :)

Comment: thanks for the webSite! can you see the code now? the idea is pretty naive, it reads the data, writes it and save the Sum at the samt time... the problem is that i no longer have 3 a,b,c it's much bigger so this code is too big and stupid.. i don't want to have like 10 "sum" and "Avgs", understand? :(

Comment: What you need is a data structure.

Comment: If you have control over the java code, a better idea would be to produce output in a portable format, like JSON.

Comment: I know I need a data sturcture, I'm not sure which one.. list. hash or Array.

Answer (score 1):

> I know I need a data sturcture, I'm not sure which one.. list. hash or Array. – user1584314

Personally, I would use a hash of arrays for the main data, with a couple auxiliary arrays to keep track of the list of words (so that they'll maintain their order) and the sums of the values in each column.  Something along the lines of:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.010;

my @word;
my %raw_values;
my $record_number = -1;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
  my ($col, $val) = $line =~ /(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*)/;
  if ($col eq 'word') {
    $record_number++;
    $word[$record_number] = $val;
  } else {
    $raw_values{$col}[$record_number] = $val;
  }
}

say 'word,', join(',', sort keys %raw_values);

for my $rec (0 .. $#word) {
  my @row = ($word[$rec]);
  for my $col (sort keys %raw_values) {
    push @row, ($raw_values{$col}[$rec] || '---');
  }
  say join ',', @row;
}

my @column_sum;
for my $col (sort keys %raw_values) { 
  my $sum = 0;
  for my $val (@{$raw_values{$col}}) {
    $sum += $val if defined $val && $val =~ /^\d+$/;
  }
  push @column_sum, $sum;
} 

say 'AVG:', join(',', map { $_ / scalar @word } @column_sum);

__DATA__
word = blabla
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
word = blabla_b
a = 11
b = 22
c = 33
word=blabla_c
a=111
c=333
word=xyzzy
a=42
b=42
c=42
```

Output:

```
word,a,b,c
blabla,1,2,3
blabla_b,11,22,33
blabla_c,111,---,333
xyzzy,42,42,42
AVG:41.25,16.5,102.75
```

**Edit:** Corrected average calculations, but, honestly, now that I've seen it (after writing my own corrected version), I have to say that I like Chris Charley's solution for calculating averages by turning `@column_sum` into a hash better than my own solution of looping an extra time over `%raw_values` to calculate `@column_sum` correctly.  I guess I must have been too wrapped up in seeing `@column_sum` as an array to consider changing it to a hash.

Comment: I haven't read through your code, but I think the average line should read like: AVE,41.25,16.5,102.75?

Comment: @ChrisCharley: You are correct! I calculated row averages instead of column averages, despite good variable names (it should obviously be `$column_sum[$col]` instead of `$column_sum[$record_number]`...). Code should now be fixed, although I'm not able to test/verify the fix just now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Dave Sherohman's solution with the 'fixes' for correct results. (@column_sum changed to hash (%column_sum).

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.010;

my @word;
my %raw_values;
my $record_number = -1;
my %column_sum;# changed to hash (was array)

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
  my ($col, $val) = $line =~ /(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*)/;
  if ($col eq 'word') {
    $record_number++;
    $word[$record_number] = $val;
  } else {
    $raw_values{$col}[$record_number] = $val;
    $column_sum{$col} += $val if $val =~ /^\d+$/; #changed from array to hash
  } 
}

say 'word,', join(',', sort keys %raw_values);

for my $rec (0 .. $#word) {
  my @row = ($word[$rec]);
  for my $col (sort keys %raw_values) {
    push @row, ($raw_values{$col}[$rec] || '---');
  }
  say join ',', @row;
}

say join(',', 'AVG', map { $column_sum{$_} / @word } sort keys %column_sum);
```

A solution using a hash of a hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my (%data, %sum, %seen, @cols, $word);
while (<DATA>) {
    my ($col, $val) = /^(\w+)\s*=\s*(\w+)$/;
    if ($col eq 'word') {
        $word = $val;   
    }
    else {
        push @cols, $col unless $seen{$col}++;
        $data{$word}{$col} = $val;
        $sum{$col} += $val;
    }
}

print join(",", 'word', @cols), "\n";

for my $word (sort keys %data) {
    print join(",", $word, map {$data{$word}{$_} || 0} @cols), "\n";    
}

print join(",", 'AVE', map {$sum{$_} / keys %data} @cols), "\n";
```

Output:

```
word,a,b,c
blabla,1,2,3
blabla_b,11,22,33
blabla_c,111,0,333
xyzzy,42,42,42
AVE,41.25,16.5,102.75
```

Comment: first of all- thank you all for your answers!! chris, your first code fails on run time with the problem: Use of uninitialized value $col in string eq at .. line 9, <DATA> line 2. although, the second answer does perfectlry what i need! excpet for - "word" was just an example, in my case this column is another head line. if the txt file has for exmple "word two" instead of "word", i get : Modification of non-creatable array value attempted, subscript -1 at  line 22, <DATA> line 1. which is :"$raw_values{$col}[$record_number] = $val;" in the code...

Comment: another question: For the row:
  my ($col, $val) = $line =~ /(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*)/ ;
How do I make it ignore any “(“ or “)” and spaces? (parenthesis) because in my real txt file the headlines are: "time (ms)" ," time (ns)", i don't know how to fix the regular expression above...